# Centering UIView

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController subclass that instantiates a UIView subclass (let's call that viewA).  Then, viewA will sometimes instantiate another UIView which we'll call viewB.

I want viewB to be centered within the view controller.

My question is, "What is a (correct) way of doing this?"

TIA

Comment: Sorry, my question is poorly worded.  I have the view controller that instantiates viewA which then instantiates viewB.  viewB is not instantiated by the view controller, so normally, it will not have access to vc's bounds, unless I pass a pointer to vc  when viewA is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many correct ways, but maybe the best one is to use the center-property:

```
[viewB setCenter: viewA.center];
```

Or maybe you need to use..

```
[viewB setCenter: viewA.navigationController.center];
```

Comment: Note: This should be done in the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method of the view controller.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful to not end up on a fraction of a point. On non-retina you need to be on full points but for retina you can be on 0.5

One way would be to use `center` and then adjust

```
viewB.center = viewA.center;
viewB.frame = CGRectIntegral(viewB.frame);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a shorter way to do it than this one:

```
CGFloat x = CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds) - viewBWidth / 2;
CGFloat y = CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds) - viewBHeight / 2;

viewB.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,viewBWidth,viewBHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
viewB.frame = [MyClass centeredFrameForSize:desiredSize inRect:viewA.bounds];


+ (CGRect)centeredFrameForSize:(CGSize)size inRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = rintf((rect.size.width - size.width)/2) + rect.origin.x;
    frame.origin.y = rintf((rect.size.height - size.height)/2) + rect.origin.y;
    frame.size = size;

    return frame;
}
```